# Python , pandas :datetime cambia el orden del mes por dia aleatioriamente en una tabla

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

lo primero muchas gracias por el interés y la molestia en contestarme.
Estoy manipulando una tabla con pandas en formato csv , y las fechas me hacen un extraño al pasarlarlas a formato datetime.
He acortado la tabla para ser lo mas expecífico posible , por ejemplo   Fecha seria la columna original en la tabla y Fecha2 la columna convertida a datetime.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
tabla=pd.read_csv("1 al 15 enero 39 rmCorta2.csv") 
tabla["Fecha2"] = pd.to_datetime(tabla["Fecha"])




RESULTADO:
    Fecha       Fecha2
66  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
67  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
68  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
69  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
70  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
71  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
72  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
73  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
74  12/01/2021  2021-12-01
75  13/01/2021  2021-01-13
76  13/01/2021  2021-01-13
```

En el indice 75 y 76 se puede apreciar como cambia el mes por el día.he probado con format=("%d,"%m,%Y") pero nada, :

```
ValueError: time data '17/01/2021' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Por que hace este cambio?
En la tabla completa también lo hace en más días pero no encuentro el porque

Agradecería mucho la ayuda , le he dado mil vueltas pero no consigo que salgan en orden correcto.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas por defecto no trata las fechas en formato europeo, pero el método [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) tiene `format` como argumento válido con el que puedes especificarle el formato de fecha con el que quiere trabajar.

Simplemente especifícalo a la hora de convertir la serie:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
tabla=pd.read_csv("1 al 15 enero 39 rmCorta2.csv") 
tabla["Fecha2"] = pd.to_datetime(tabla["Fecha"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Hola @Cesar, tienes razón en el método to_datetime de pandas, pero hay un problema a la hora de impromir el formato, y es que internamente cuando hace el casting a datetime64, sale por defecto el formato Y-m-d H:M:S. Lo he estado probando y la única manera que he encontrado es que para salga en ese formato, dejarlo como string. con un tabla["fecha2"] = tabla['Fecha'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')).

Comment: Como digo da error ValueError: time data '17/01/2021' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match), de todas maneras no entiendo como unas fechas salen bien y otras no, deberian de salir todas mal no?

Comment: No exactamente. Las primeras fechas sí es capaz de parsearlas con formato %m-%d-%Y automáticamente (el formato por defecto) porque cumple con el criterio: 12/01/2021 es el 1 de diciembre de 2021 en formato americano, pero también es el 12 de enero de 2021 en el formato europeo